# Troubleshooting "TemplateDoesNotExist at /accounts/login/" - Django auth setup

Tags: django, templates, user-registration

I am trying to get django-registration up and running on my newbie setup on Eclipse.

I see that django has a lot of helper views to handle login, logout, registration, etc within the included `django.contrib.auth` app.  I included the `auth` urls as instructed in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#using-the-views) but login still isn't working.  When running the local server and hitting the `/accounts/login/` endpoint, it sees there is an endpoint there but error with `TemplateDoesNotExist`.

I'm trying to figure out why the built in login view isn't working.  See error below:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /accounts/login/

registration/login.html

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/accounts/login/
Django Version: 1.2.4
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value: registration/login.html

Exception Location: C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py in find_template, line 138
Python Executable: C:\Python25\python.exe
Python Version: 2.5.4
Python Path: [
  'C:\\dd\\ddproject\\src',
  'C:\\dd\\ddproject\\src',
  'C:\\Python25\\Lib\\site-packages\\django',
  'C:\\Python25\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\contrib',
  'C:\\Python25\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\contrib\\admin',
  'C:\\Python25\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\db',
  'C:\\Python25\\Lib\\site-packages\\Django-1.2.4-py2.5.egg-info',
  'C:\\Python25\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\contrib\\auth',
  'C:\\Python25\\Lib\\site-packages\\django_registration-0.7-py2.5.egg',
  'C:\\Python25\\Lib\\site-packages\\django_registration-0.7-py2.5.egg\\registration',
  'C:\\Python25',
  'C:\\Python25\\DLLs',
  'C:\\Python25\\lib',
  'C:\\Python25\\lib\\lib-tk',
  'C:\\Python25\\lib\\plat-win',
  'C:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages',
  'C:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL',
  'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\python25.zip'
]
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you're using django-registration you must create the registration templates yourself. By default these should be setup to be within a url path of /accounts/.

Comment: Yep that's my problem.   I was naively wondering how the templates would magically get generated from the egg directory!   Thanks!

Comment: Why not a default one, django?!

Answer (score 5):

Did you define your template path in the settings.py

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'template').replace('\\','/'),
)
```

Comment: incase it isn't totally clear, this adds /path/to/settings/template to the TEMPLATE_DIRS

Comment: Yes I added a template dir to the Settings file.   My mistake was thinking the template dir would magically get some registration screens generated by the django-registration code!